# Material-ui pagination using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-hooks, material-ui, react-state

I am using an API to fetch and render the data it into cards. I want to add pagination and for this I'm using the [React Pagination component](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/).
I'm rendering 9 cards per page, the page number and the number of cards are determined by the API url.
The problem is that when I click on a pagination button it seems to call the API twice, one for the first page and one for the page that I'm requesting. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**This is the part where I fetch the data and try to update the page number:**

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchBeerData(currentPage);
 }, [currentPage]);

 const fetchBeerData = async pageNumber => {
   try {
     const { data } = await axios.get(
       `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${pageNumber}&per_page=9`
     );
     console.log(data);
     setBeers(data);
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
 };

 const handlePageChange = e => {
   setCurrentPage(e.target.innerText);
   fetchBeerData(currentPage);
   console.log('page nr:', e.target);
 };
```

I'm passing the `handlePageChange` function as a prop to the pagination component, like so:

```
<PaginationButtons
        handlePageChange={handlePageChange}
        page={currentPage}
      />
```

**And this is the pagination component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
}));

export const PaginationButtons = ({ handlePageChange }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Pagination
        count={10}
        hidePrevButton
        hideNextButton
        size='large'
        onChange={e => handlePageChange(e)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

*I have created a codesandbox as well, here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-water-0fkgc?file=/src/components/Home.js)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your handlePageChange you are setting **currentPage** state which trigger **useEffect** to call **fetchBeerData(currentPage)** then again you are calling **fetchBeerData(currentPage)**

```
 const handlePageChange = e => {
   setCurrentPage(e.target.innerText);
  // fetchBeerData(currentPage);
   console.log('page nr:', e.target);
 };
```

Comment: Oh I see.. But how could I make it so that the useEffect is not triggered? If I remove currentPage from the dependency array it seems like I'm getting random pages

Comment: just removed this line  fetchBeerData(currentPage) From your  handlePageChange. It work fine.. furthermore if you don't want to trigger useEffect on state change then just send the current page value direct to fetch like  fetchBeerData(e.target.innerText) and remove dependency array. But simple solution is to remove fetchbeerData() from handler.